# How do I eliminate left recursion in discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I am working on a problem and the grammar is below.
$A\rightarrow AA$* 
 
 $\rightarrow AA+$
 
 $\rightarrow a$ 
The formula for elimination is 
$A\rightarrow Aα|β$ 
$A\rightarrow βA'$
$A'\rightarrow αA'$
 
I just don't know how to use that formula if I have two AA instead of just one A 

$A->aA'$
$A'\rightarrow A+A'$ 
  $\rightarrow A*A'$ 
  $\rightarrow a$ 
However, I still have one $A$ in there. How do I get rid of that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it can help you.

> **Elimination of Left-Recursion**
>
> For each rule which contains a left-recursive option,
>
> $$A \to A\alpha|\beta$$
>
> introduce a new nonterminal A' and rewrite the
>   rule as
>
> \begin{align}
>  &A \to \beta A' \\ 
>  &A' \to  \alpha A'|\epsilon
> \end{align}
>
> there may be more than one left-recursive part on the right-hand side.
>   The general rule is to replace:
>
> $$A \to A  \alpha_1 | \alpha_2|...| \alpha_n|\beta_1|\beta_2| ...
>  |\beta_m $$
>
> by
>    \begin{align}
>  &A \to \beta_1  A' | \beta_2  A'| ...|   \beta_m A' \\
>  &A' \to \epsilon | \alpha_1 A' |  \alpha_2A' | ...|  \alpha_n A'
> \end{align}
>
> ---

$ A\to AA*|AA+|a $

we can write it as:

$A\to AB|AC|a \\
B \to A* \\
C \to A+ $

---

1. $A\to AB|a :\\
     \,\,\,A\to aA'\\
    \,\,\,\,A' \to A*A'|\epsilon$
2. $A \to AC|a :\\
    \,\,\,A \to aA'\\
    \,\,\,\,A' \to A+A'|\epsilon$

combine those two:

$A \to aA'\\ 
A' \to A+A'|A*A'|\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, the formula for removing left-recursion (and replacing it with right-recursion) involves replacing all instances of this rule:
\begin{gather}
A \rightarrow A\alpha\ |\ \beta\\
\end{gather}
with this rule:
\begin{gather}
A \rightarrow \beta A'\\
A' \rightarrow \alpha A'\ |\ \epsilon
\end{gather}

Your grammar is given by the following rules:
\begin{gather}
A \rightarrow AA*\ |\ AA+\ |\ a\\
\end{gather}

Here, we must eliminate left-recursion in two places, using the above rule for each case:

1. $A \rightarrow AA*\ |\ a$ (here, $\alpha = A*$ and $\beta=a$)
   \begin{gather}
   A \rightarrow a A'\\
   A' \rightarrow A*A'\ |\ \epsilon
   \end{gather}
2. $A \rightarrow AA+\ |\ a$ (here, $\alpha = A+$ and $\beta=a$).
   \begin{gather}
   A \rightarrow a A'\\
   A' \rightarrow A+A'\ |\ \epsilon
   \end{gather}

Combining these, we obtain:
\begin{gather}
A \rightarrow a A'\\
A' \rightarrow A+A'\ |\ A*A'\ |\ \epsilon
\end{gather}

Answer (score 0):

Is this the grammar you've come up with?

> A->aA'
>   A'->A+A'
>   A'->A*A'
>   A'->a

If so, this grammar does not have any left-recursion, so it looks like you're already finished.

(However, shouldn't the last rule produce the empty string instead of "a"?)